# Proof that $5x^3$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$

Tags: epsilon-delta

We define function $f(x) = 5x^3$.

To prove: $f$ is continuous in x, with $x \in \mathbb R.$

Suppose, $\epsilon > 0,$ we choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5(3x^2 + |3x| +1)}$, then for all $x \in \mathbb R$, with
$|x - c| \lt \delta$, we have $|5x^3 - 5c^3| < \epsilon$. We also suppose $\delta < 1.$

|$5x^3 - 5c^3$| = 5|$x^3 - c^3$| = 5|$x - c$||$x^2 + c^2$ + cx| < 5 δ|$x^2 + c^2$ + cx|

|$x^2+c^2+xc$| < |$x^2 + (x + 1)^2+ x(x+1)$| so, |$x^2+c^2+xc$|< $3x^2 + |3x| + 1$

5 δ|$x^2 + c^2$ + cx| < 5 δ ($3x^2 + |3x| + 1$) < ϵ.

Is this proof sufficient?

Comment: You seem to be trying to use mathjax, and doing quite well.  Please note that you can surround entire expressions, within a single pair of dollar signs, so it goes much more quickly.  Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Click on "Edit" (left bottom).  I've formatted a bit to demonstrate full formatting of expressions.  And for epsilon, use `\epsilon`, and for delta, use `\delta`.  Otherwise, keep up formatting efforts!

Comment: @amWhy ok thanks for the editing and tips

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for your efforts here!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> It looks as if you're proving $f$ is continuous at $c$. If that's right, your choice of $\delta$ can depend on $c$, but not on $x$. (Fixing this may simply be a matter of exchanging a few $x$s with $cs; I haven't checked your calculations carefully.)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! Can you explain why I am proofing that f is continuous in c and not in x?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't have your $\delta$ depending on $x$, as you haven't said anything about $x$ yet.

You'll need to 'work backwards' as I've always been taught, begin from what you want to prove to get an expression for $\delta$.